# sun.misc.Unsafe: How to get the Bytes from an address

Tags: memory, memory-address, unsafe

I have heard there is a way to read a value from the memory (as long as the memory is controlled by the JVM).
But how do I get the bytes from the address `8E5203` for example? There is a method called `getBytes(long)`. Can I use this?

Thanks a lot!
Pete

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly access any memory location! It has to be managed by the JVM. Either security exception or `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` occurs. This could crash the JVM itself. But if we allocate memory from the code, one can access the bytes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Unsafe unsafe = null;

        try {
            Field field = sun.misc.Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            unsafe = (sun.misc.Unsafe) field.get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }

        byte size = 1;//allocate 1 byte
        long allocateMemory = unsafe.allocateMemory(size);
        //write the bytes
        unsafe.putByte(allocateMemory, "a".getBytes()[0]);
        byte readValue = unsafe.getByte(allocateMemory);            
        System.out.println("value : " + new String(new byte[]{ readValue}));
}
```